# django ModelForm not capturing uploaded images

Tags: python, django, modelform

Hi there I'm trying to create a form for a user on my site to be able to add a product, I made the form using ModelForm and I have managed to render it in my template but it's not functioning as required. On submitting the form I keep getting validation errors that images have not been submitted yet I did add them, any ideas

Model

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.FloatField()
    image_182x182 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/')
    image_1200x1200 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_600x600 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_600x600_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    image_300x300 = models.ImageField(upload_to='pdt_imgs/alt_imgs/')
    img_array = [image_1200x1200, image_600x600, image_600x600_2]
    sku = models.IntegerField()
    available = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    discount = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(SubCategory, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return  reverse('pdt_detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    def get_add_to_cart_url(self):
        return reverse('add-to-cart', args= [str(self.id)] )
```

Form

```
from .models import Product
from django.forms import ModelForm


class ProductForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = [
            'name', 'price', 'image_182x182', 'image_1200x1200', 'image_600x600',
            'image_600x600_2', 'image_300x300', 'sku', 'available', 'discount', 
            'category', 'seller'
            ]
```

Views

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from .decorators import seller_required
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from store.models import Product
from store.forms import ProductForm
from django.contrib import messages


@method_decorator( seller_required , name='dispatch')
class SellerProductAddView(CreateView):
    model = Product
    form_class = ProductForm
    template_name = 'seller_add_pdt.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        product = form.save()
        messages.success(self.request, "Your Product was succesfully added")
        return redirect('seller_add_pdt')
```

template

```
<div class="ps-block__content">
   <form class="ps-form--account-setting"  method="post">
         {% csrf_token %}
         {{ form|crispy }}
         <div class="form-group submit">
             <button type="submit" class="ps-btn">Add</button>
         </div>
   </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   <form class="ps-form--account-setting"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: To help him out the reason his solution works Is because at first I did not specify an encoding type to handle my image files being uploaded so the form does not read submitted files but once the encoding type is specified this is taken care of